# How to collapse the accordion when minus is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to close this accordion when minus is clicked. The minus sign appears when the accordion is in expanded state.
Currently the expanded is only closed when another h3 is clicked.

I tried removing class opened in h3 and it didn't work. Also if you could keep the animation on collapse that would be great.

Tried this didn't work

```
$('.accordion > h3').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
    }
```

```js
"use strict";

var head, //".accordion > h3"
 content, //".accordion > div"
 animateTime = 500;

//при клике по заголовку...
$(".accordion > h3").click(function () {

 head = $(this);
 content = $(this).next("div");

 //Перебрать элементы массива (все h3)
 $(".accordion > h3").each(function (index) {
  let elem = $(this);

  //Проверить, есть ли уже растрытые блоки. Если есть - закрыть.
  if (elem.attr("class") === "opened") {
   elem.removeClass("opened");
   elem.next("div").stop().animate({
    height: '0'
   }, animateTime);
  }
 });

 //Добавить заголовку раскрываемого блока класс "opened"
 head.addClass("opened");

 //Плавно раскрыть блок с контентом
 autoHeightAnimate(content, animateTime);

 //Прокрутить страницу до раскрытого заголовка
 //это нужно, чтобы контент не уплывал вверх, особенно на маленьких экранах и при большом объеме контента
 setTimeout(function () {
  $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: head.offset().top
  }, animateTime);
 }, animateTime);

 /*****/
 /* Функция для - animate height: auto */
 function autoHeightAnimate(element, time) {
  var curHeight = element.height(), // Получить высоту по умолчанию
   autoHeight = element.css('height', 'auto').height(); // Сделать высоту auto

  element.height(curHeight); //Переустановить высоту
  element.stop().animate({
   height: autoHeight
  }, time);
 }

});
```

```css
.accordion > h3 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px; height:60px; border-radius:8px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 line-height: 34px;
 background: #f1f2f3;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.accordion > h3 div{padding:12px 0 0 70px !important;}
.accordion > h3::before {
 content: '+'; border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 background: orange;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center; padding:12px 0 0 0 !important;
 
}
.accordion p{padding:8px 0 8px 0 !important; margin:0 !important; overflow:auto;}
.accordion > h3.opened {color: #333;}
.accordion > h3.opened::before {content: '-'; line-height: 110%; background: #80cc26;}
.accordion > div {height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
              <h3>
                <div>
                  <h3>Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas</h3>
                </div>
              </h3>
                <div>
                  <p></p>
                  <h1>Vulputate</h1>
                  <p></p>
                  <h1>Commodo sed egestas egestas</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              <h3>
                <div>
                  <h3>Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque</h3>
                </div>
              </h3>
                <div>
                  <p></p>
                  <h1>Commodo sed</h1
                  <p></p>
                  <h1>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p></p>
                </div>
                <h3>
                <div>
                  <h3>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</h3>
                </div>
              </h3>
                <div>
                  <p></p>
                  <h1>Pretium viverra suspendisse 
                  <p></p>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                    <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a .toogle() method that you can use I think. You can find docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and 
provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:** In your code you `addClass('opened')` and run `autoHeightAnimate` and those will fire each time you click the `<h3>` So you need an `if` statement condition to make the opposite action

<sup>**[1]**</sup> To check for class use `.hasClass()` Not `.attr('class')`

<sup>**[2]**</sup> No need to loop through the `<h3>` It will be easier to check if `this` `<h3>` hasClass `opened` or not then make the action and/else the opposite action .. Please read comments in the code below

```js
"use strict";

var head, //".accordion > h3"
content, //".accordion > div"
animateTime = 500;

//при клике по заголовку...
$(".accordion > h3").click(function () {

  var head = $(this);
  var content = $(this).next("div");
  var not_head = $(".accordion > h3").not(head);
  var not_content = $(".accordion > h3").not(head).next('div');

  //Проверить, есть ли уже растрытые блоки. Если есть - закрыть.
  if (head.hasClass("opened")) {  // check if this h3 hasclass opened
    $(".accordion > h3").removeClass("opened");   // remove opened class from all h3
    $(".accordion > h3").next("div").stop().animate({  // close all next div
    height: '0'
    }, animateTime);
  }else{
    not_head.removeClass('opened');  // remove opened class from h3 but not the clicked one
    not_content.stop().animate({  // close next div but not the next of the clicked h3
    height: '0'
    }, animateTime);
    head.addClass('opened');   // addclass opened to this h3
    //Плавно раскрыть блок с контентом
    autoHeightAnimate(content, animateTime); // open the next div of this h3
  }


  //Прокрутить страницу до раскрытого заголовка
  //это нужно, чтобы контент не уплывал вверх, особенно на маленьких экранах и при большом объеме контента
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: head.offset().top
    }, animateTime);
  }, animateTime);
});


/*****/
/* Функция для - animate height: auto */
function autoHeightAnimate(element, time) {
  var curHeight = element.height(), // Получить высоту по умолчанию
  autoHeight = element.css('height', 'auto').height(); // Сделать высоту auto

  element.height(curHeight); //Переустановить высоту
  element.stop().animate({
  height: autoHeight
  }, time);
 }
```

```css
.accordion > h3 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px; height:60px; border-radius:8px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 line-height: 34px;
 background: #f1f2f3;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.accordion > h3 div{padding:12px 0 0 70px !important;}
.accordion > h3::before {
 content: '+'; border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 background: orange;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center; padding:12px 0 0 0 !important;
 
}
.accordion p{padding:8px 0 8px 0 !important; margin:0 !important; overflow:auto;}
.accordion > h3.opened {color: #333;}
.accordion > h3.opened::before {content: '-'; line-height: 110%; background: #80cc26;}
.accordion > div {height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>
    <div>
      <h3>Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas</h3>
    </div>
  </h3>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <h1>Vulputate</h1>
      <p></p>
      <h1>Commodo sed egestas egestas</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  <h3>
    <div>
      <h3>Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque</h3>
    </div>
  </h3>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <h1>Commodo sed</h1
      <p></p>
      <h1>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <h3>
    <div>
      <h3>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</h3>
    </div>
  </h3>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <h1>Pretium viverra suspendisse 
      <p></p>
      <ul>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti</li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Additional:**  No need to write the function inside the click event .. you can pull it out the click event and you'll still can use it